# Display items from an associative array on a two column table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table, associative

I'm trying to display item from associative array into a two column table, using this associative array
`foreach($this->inventory as $ID => $Info)`.

```
"<table width ='100%'>\n"; 
 foreach($this->inventory as $ID => $Info) {
    echo"<tr>";   
    echo"<td>".$Info['name'] <br>$Info['description']." </td>";
    echo"<td>".$Info['name'] <br>$Info['description']."</td>"; 
    echo"</tr>";
}
</table>
```

The problem is it displays each item twice on each row.
I want it to display some like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|Name: shoes                      |Name: bag
|Description: nike                |Description: swing bag
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
|Name: socks                      |Name: ear phones
|Description: black and white     |Description: beats
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
|Name: earrings                   |Name: phone
|Description: diamond  studs      |Description: blackberry
```

but I'm getting this instead:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|Name: shoes                      | Name: shoes
|Description: nike                | Description: nike
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
|Name: bag                        | Name: bag 
|Description: swing bag           |Description: swing bag 
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
|Name: ear phones                 |Name: ear phones
|Description: beats               |Description: beats
```

Comment: it says you are trying, but not what problems you've encountered. Code seems straightforward assumning data keys match and `$this->inventory` returns an array

Comment: @charlietfl I've refined the question included as much details as possible. thank you

Comment: ooooo that's simple....you duplicated the output code...never noticed that part before...well really didn't know what was expected either

Comment: need a counter that checks for `% 2` so you only close the `<tr>` on every second pass of loop and remove one of the `TD` output lines you have now

Comment: is `$this->inventory` an array where $ID is the index, or is it an object where `$ID` is a key? If index....can use `for` and increment by 2

Answer (score 1):

I created CSS for this pseudo-table in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hnek2/

Now you can use this PHP:

```
echo('<div class="tbl">');
foreach($this->inventory as $ID => $Info) {
    echo('<div class="block">');   
    echo('<p>Name: ' . $Info['name'] . '</p><p>Description: ' . $Info['description'] . '</p>');
    echo('</div>');
}
echo('</div>');
```

Comment: good example of why tables shouldn't be used for non tabular data

Comment: @Qiqa: Accept this answer if you like it and if it solved your problem.